# Not able to display a dicom image using cornerstone.js

Tags: javascript, dicom, cornerstonejs

I'm trying to display a Dicom Image using the cornerstone library. I have used the jsminimal example code from https://github.com/cornerstonejs/cornerstone/blob/master/example/jsminimal/index.html. The js files I've included are cornerstone.js and exampleImageIdLoader.js taken from the same link above.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">

            <h1>
                jsminimal/index.html
            </h1>

            <h3>This is an example of the minimal use of cornerstone driven by javascript</h3>

            <br>
            <br>

            <h3>In this example, javascript is used to image enable a div.</h3>

            <br>
            <br>

            <div id="dicomImage" style="width:512px;height:512px">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="cornerstone.js"></script>
    <script>window.cornerstone || document.write('<script src="https://unpkg.com/cornerstone-core@2.3.0">\x3C/script>')</script>

    <script src="exampleImageIdLoader.js"></script>
    <script>
    const imageId = 'vhf.151.dcm';
    const element = document.getElementById('dicomImage');
    cornerstone.enable(element);
    cornerstone.loadImage(imageId).then(function(image) {
        cornerstone.displayImage(element, image);
    });
</script>
</html>
```

The errors I'm facing are :

Error: loadImageFromImageLoader: no image loader for imageId cornerstone.js:3361:11

loadImageFromImageLoader file:/absolute path to cornerstone.js/cornerstone.js:3361

loadImage file:/absolute path to cornerstone.js>/cornerstone.js:3402

file:/absolute path to the html file/imageViewer.html:35

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert `cornerstoneWADOImageLoader`.

Documentation: https://github.com/cornerstonejs/cornerstoneWADOImageLoader